# Specify an edgeLabel in graphML that tinkerpop can understand

Tags: gephi, tinkerpop3, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have been struggling to load a graphml in to Tinkerpop3.

```
Graph graphMLGraph = TinkerGraph.open();
graphMLGraph.io(IoCore.graphml()).readGraph(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

While loading, I want the the edges to have a label.

```
graphTraversalSource.E().toStream().forEach(edge -> {
      System.out.println(edge.label());
    });
```

The above code always prints the labels as `edge` for all the edges in the graphml. My graphml snippets.

```
<edge id="1" source="1" target="3">
<data key="edgelabel">belongs-to</data>
<data key="weight">1.0</data>
</edge>
<edge id="2" source="1" target="4">
<data key="weight">1.0</data>
<data key="edgelabel">part-of</data>
</edge>
```

And the key definition

```
<key attr.name="Edge Label" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="edgelabel"/>
```

I am use DSE 5.1.3's java driver and tinkerpop 3.2.5 is used via a transitive dependency and used Gephi to author the graphml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, your edge label will be recognized if you do define the key as:

```
<key id="labelE" for="edge" attr.name="labelE" attr.type="string" />
```

The important part being that the `attr.name` is defaulted to "labelE". See the IO Reference documentation for GraphML [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/dev/io/#graphml). Note that the default can be changed when you instantiate the `GraphMLReader.Builder` object by setting the `edgeLabelKey` value on the builder itself.